# Update query that will update a column from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following temporary table #tempGd that contain 3 value in one column (22,39,3). I would like to update my revision table as such but I was not successful.

```
UPDATE revision
SET date = ('2023-06-03', '2023-06-03','2024-06-03')
where revisionid IN (SELECT revisionid FROM #tempGD);
```

Comment: `date = ('2023-06-03', '2023-06-03','2024-06-03')` Is it this line that causes an error? Looks like it should

Comment: What are you actually trying to set the `date` column to? Or are you trying to set more than one columns value with that

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `#` for temp tables, that's SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same date 3 time, I assume you thought you woudl need 3 date values, but as they are all the same, all you ned to do it this

```
UPDATE revision
SET date = '2023-06-03'
where revisionid IN (SELECT revisionid FROM tempGD);
```

Comment: I have a feeling that in his real application he may need different dates depending on the revisionid. So it should probably be a `CASE` expression.

Comment: With hind sight you could be right @Barmar